# How do you reference HTML/ASP elements with C# objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm new to ASP.NET and C#, I've primarily worked with Java. I want to dynamically add nodes to a tree view. I've followed a few tutorials but whenever I implement them they do not appear to work. I keep getting an error: "The name 'MyTreeView' does not exist in the current context".

Here's the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace LocalTest
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                MyTreeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Node1"));
                MyTreeView.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("ChildNode"));
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

And the HTML/ASP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TreeView ID="MyTreeView" Runat="server">

        </asp:TreeView>
    </div>
    </form>   
</body>
</html>
```

"MyTreeView" is the ID of the treeview contained in the Default.aspx file.

The few tutorials I have followed *seem* to access the treeview directly with its ID as seen above which makes very little sense to me. For instance, if I were to do this in Android I would have to use the *findViewById* and establish a link between the XML and the Object.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've bumbled around this site for a bit and I'veonly found similar issues but I cannot get a clear answer.

Thank you.

Comment: how did you created your ASP.NET page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code above, you are using what's known as ASP.Net `WebForms` where there are "server side" controls (e.g. `<asp:TreeView ID="MyTreeView" Runat="server">`)

The "page" (html aspx) needs to somehow "wire itself" to the code (c# file). It will need a "server-side" directive like so:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormsApplication.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

 //...the rest of the html goes here plus web controls, etc.
```

At which point, you can see stuff like `Inherits="WebFormsApplication.WebForm1"` that maps to the `Class`:

```
namespace WebFormsApplication
{
   public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
   ....
```

found in the `WebForm1.aspx.cs` file, also in the directive `CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"`

So voila :)

> *establish a link between the XML and the Object.*

Hth...

Comment: That removed the error. That was the clearest explanation from a selection of many, many tutorials. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Cian - Cool! Be "gentle" with me when I get deeper into Java/Droid world where I will likely have the same questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have TreeView control in default.aspx. It is in .html file and default.aspx.cs can not see TreeView control.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing `Page` directive in your asp.net page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
```